# What is the best way to generate a potentially empty sequence of integers?

Tags: r

`seq(n,m)` is not able to generate an empty sequence,
since the direction of steps in the sequence `seq(n,m)` switches from upward to downward
when `m` is getting smaller than `n`:

- `seq(1,2)` has two elements: 1,2
- `seq(1,1)` has one element: 1
- `seq(1,0)` has two elements: 1,0.

Unfortunately `seq` doesn't have an optional argument to force the direction of the steps.
I have already found two bugs in R packages where `seq(1,n)` (or `1:n`) was meant to be the
sequence of all positive integers less than or equal to `n`, but `n` was potentially 0.
Currently my expedients are unsightly constructions like

```
 ifelse(n>=1,seq(1,n),integer(0))
```

or

```
 seq(1,length.out=max(n,0))
```

or, if n is at least nonnegative,

```
 seq(0,n)[-1]
```

At a first glance the first one doesn't look so bad, but if `n` is a longer expression, they do.
The last one does't work if `n` is negative:

```
> n <- -3
> seq(0,n)[-1]
[1] -1 -2 -3
```

Are there any better ideas to generate a potentially empty sequence of integers?

Comment: "I have already found two bugs in R packages where seq(1,n) (or 1:n) was meant to be the sequence of all positive integers less than or equal to n, but n was potentially 0." --> `seq_len(n)`

Comment: "if n is a longer expression they look bad", just define your seq function, e.g. : `myseq <- function(n,m) if(m < n) integer() else seq(n,m)`

Comment: @Roland: `seq_len(n)` throws an error if `n` is negative. `seq_len(max(0,n))` works, but is not better than `seq(1,length.out=max(0,n))`. And if the sequence shouldn't start at 1 it's getting worse.

Comment: Of course, `seq_len` throws an error if `n` is negative. And that's a good thing. It's the task of the programmer to make sure that `n` can only take reasonable values. Please read my comment again, including the quote. Also, please consider asking a question with a clearly defined, specific objective.

Comment: @Roland: Look at my second question, which I answered myself. There you can see a bug that is based on the fact that `1:0` is not empty.

Comment: What is your "second question"? Again, if you need a sequence from 1 to n with n > 0 and n can become 0, you should use `seq_len`. Usually, n < 0 is then a result of a programming mistake and you should be happy to get an error.

Comment: @Roland: My "second question" is chronologically the second one. Unfortunately I don't know how to add a link into a comment. But you can just sort the list of my questions by "newest". And n<0 doesn't have to be a programming mistake in general.

Comment: If n <0 is not a programming mistake, handle it appropriately with an `if else` construct.

Comment: @Roland: `if else` is what I've already suggested. And still, this topic remains to be a pitfall, even for R-developers.

Comment: I don't see any pitfall. But good luck with whatever you are trying to solve.

Comment: @Roland: Have you looked up my second question? There you see the pitfall. In most programming languages `for (i in 1:n) {...}` means "run through the loop at most `n` times", not so in R. But sometimes R-developers don't take care of that.

Comment: And that's a programming mistake ... One shouldn't use `1:n` in a for loop if one can't be absolutely sure that n > 0.

Comment: If you feel the need to discuss this further, try the [R-public](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public)  chatroom.

Comment: @Roland: The programming mistake is not n<=0. But the behaviour of the `seq` function I am pulling attention to leads to programming mistakes. I suggest to calm down now. StackOverflow is already complaining about the number of comments.

Comment: I'm perfectly calm. Feel free to develop your own derivate of `seq` and provide it in a package.

Comment: How this `myseq(n,m)` can be uglier than this `ifelse(n>=0,seq(n,m),integer(0))` (that's, by the way, wrong) ? Also, R construct `for(i in 1:n)` is not exactly the same as C-like construct `for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)`, it more like `for each element i in a sequence from 1 to n (n being possibly a negative number)`. So, it's not a bug, it's just you're using something not properly.

Comment: @digEmAll: Ugliness is a matter of taste, I've deleted my comment. Indeed, R's for loops `for (i in 1:n)` are not the same as for-loops in most prgramming languages. And that is exactly the point. At the time the code is written R developers often forget to take care of this pitfall and use the for-loop improperly . It is a COMMON pitfall, even for experienced programmers, since for-loops are often handled subconsciously, I guess. The purpose of my question was to draw attention to that fact.

Comment: @mra68: in that sense, R has a lot more dangerous pitfalls for not native R developers. Like `data.frame` subsetting argument `drop` not being false by default (a subset of data.frame must return a data.frame even if you have one column !), default factors conversion in data.frame, `T` and `F` not being alternative reserved words for TRUE and FALSE but just variables (I once defined a flag called `F` and set to `TRUE`, since then I never use `T` or `F` but the full version)...etc... for-loop problem is probably one of the less serious ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not happy with the way `for` loops work in R, maybe you would prefer `foreach` loops with the iterators package:

```
library(iterators)
library(foreach)

foreach(i = icount(3), .combine = "c") %do% {i}
#[1] 1 2 3
foreach(i = icount(-3), .combine = "c") %do% {i}
#NULL
foreach(i = icount(0), .combine = "c") %do% {i}
#NULL
```