# R: avoiding loops

Tags: r

I load a json format file. Sample data `sampleData`(Not all variables are included in the sample):

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$id
[1] "000018ac-04ef-4270-81e6-9e3cb8274d31"

[[1]]$currentCompany
[1] ""

[[1]]$skills
list()


[[2]]
[[2]]$id
[1] "00000259-7c1c-4db6-9a2a-6d450626fbac"

[[2]]$currentCompany
[1] "Super Market 2"

[[2]]$skills
[[2]]$skills[[1]]
[[2]]$skills[[1]]$name
[1] "OpenGL"

[2]]$skills
[[2]]$skills[[1]]
[[2]]$skills[[1]]$type
[1] "link"    

[2]]$skills
[[2]]$skills[[2]]
[[2]]$skills[[2]]$name
[1] "C"

[2]]$skills
[[2]]$skills[[2]]
[[2]]$skills[[2]]$type
[1] "link"
```

So from this file I want to extract the skills in a list. I am using the following code:

```
skill <- list()
for (i in 1:length(sampleData){
    skill[i][1] <- 'empty'
    for (j in 1:length(sampleData[[i]]$skills)){
        if (length(sampleData[[i]]$skills)==0){
            skill[[i]][j] <- NA
        }else{
            skill[[i]][j] <- json[[i]]$skills[[j]]$name  
        }

   }
}
```

Results:

```
[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] "OpenGL"               "C"
```

The results are ok. My question is there a way to impliment it more efficient or elegant? For example without using loops? Furthermore I am using this line of code `skill[i][1] <- 'empty'` cause without initializing inside an error pop ups `Error in`*tmp*`[[i]] : subscript out of bounds`. Any wat to avoid this dump initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
sampleData <-
  list(
    list(
      id = "000018ac-04ef-4270-81e6-9e3cb8274d31",
      curruentCompany = "",
      skills = list()
    ),
    list(
      id = "00000259-7c1c-4db6-9a2a-6d450626fbac",
      curruentCompany = "",
      skills = list(
        list( name = "OpenGL" ),
        list( name = "C" )
      )
    )   
  )

A <- unlist(sampleData,recursive=FALSE)
n <- which(names(A)=="skills")

skill_L <- A[n]
skill <- lapply(skill_L,unlist)
```

In `skill_L` the skills are still lists, in `skill` they are vectors:

```
> skill_L
$skills
list()

$skills
$skills[[1]]
$skills[[1]]$name
[1] "OpenGL"


$skills[[2]]
$skills[[2]]$name
[1] "C"



> skill
$skills
NULL

$skills
    name     name 
"OpenGL"      "C" 

>
```

The case of "no skills" is represented by `NULL`, not `NA`. If this is not appropriate, another application of a function from the `apply`-family is needed:

```
> skill[sapply(skill,is.null)] <- NA
> skill
$skills
[1] NA

$skills
    name     name 
"OpenGL"      "C" 

>
```

The reason for the `subscript out of bounds` error in your solution might be that R runs through the `for`-loop

```
for (i in 1:0){...}
```

not 0 times but two times, onces for i=1 and onces for i=0. See for example the [heated debate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235461/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-potentially-empty-sequence-of-integers) I had with one of our R giants about this topic.

Benchmark test:

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------

mra68 <- function(data)
{
  A <- unlist(data,recursive=FALSE)  
  skill_vec <- lapply(A[which(names(A)=="skills")],unlist)
  skill_vec[sapply(skill_vec,is.null)] <- NA
  skill_vec
}

#--------------------------------------------------------------

thothal <- function(sampleData) {
  lapply(sampleData, function(l) {
    if (length(l$skills) == 0) {
      NA
    } else {
      unlist(l$skills)
    }
  })
}

#--------------------------------------------------------------

createData <- function(length.out) {
  ret <- vector("list", length.out)
  for (i in seq_len(length.out)) {
    skills.n <- sample(0:10, 1)
    skills <- vector("list", skills.n)
    for (j in seq_len(skills.n)) {
      skills[[j]] <- list(name = paste0("skill = ", j, ", id = ", i))
    }
    ret[[i]] <- list(id = paste("id", i),
                     currentCompany = paste("Company", i),
                     skills = skills)
  }
  ret
}
#--------------------------------------------------------------

library(microbenchmark)

data <- createData(1e+4)

microbenchmark(mra68(data),
               thothal(data), unit = "s")
```

-

```
> microbenchmark(mra68(data),
+                thothal(data), unit = "s")
Unit: seconds
          expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
   mra68(data) 0.1531227 0.2078011 0.2779383 0.2946479 0.3299953 0.5017640   100
 thothal(data) 0.1664253 0.2260693 0.3168359 0.3277690 0.3726730 0.7728963   100
>
```

And if `NULL` instead of `NA` is ok:

```
mra68_NULL <- function(data)
{
  A <- unlist(data,recursive=FALSE)  
  skill_vec <- lapply(A[which(names(A)=="skills")],unlist)
  skill_vec
}
```

.

```
> microbenchmark(mra68_NULL(data),
+                mra68(data),
+                thothal(data), unit = "s" )
Unit: seconds
             expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 mra68_NULL(data) 0.1019852 0.1439472 0.2177345 0.2501026 0.2554921 0.3492776   100
      mra68(data) 0.1141832 0.1871851 0.2647803 0.2884579 0.3091937 0.7359363   100
    thothal(data) 0.1216594 0.2031117 0.2885294 0.3148583 0.3344948 0.8078336   100
>
```

The case that there are several fields:

```
sampleData <-
  list(
    list(
      id = "000018ac-04ef-4270-81e6-9e3cb8274d31",
      curruentCompany = "",
      skills = list()
    ),
    list(
      id = "00000259-7c1c-4db6-9a2a-6d450626fbac",
      curruentCompany = "",
      skills = list(
        list( type = "link",
              name = "OpenGL" ),
        list( name = "C" )
      )
    ),
    list(
      id = "00000259-7c1c-4db6-9a2a-6d450626fbac",
      curruentCompany = "",
      skills = list(
        list( aaa  = "X" ),
        list( type = "Link",
              name = "abc",
              bbb  = "xyz" ),
        list( name = "E",
              aaa  = "123" )
      )
    )
  )

#--------------------------------------------------------------

A <- unlist(sampleData,recursive=FALSE)
n <- which(names(A)=="skills")

skill_L <- A[n]

f <- function(x){
  if (length(x)>0){x[sapply(x,is.null)] <- NA} else {x<-NA}
  return(x)
}

skill <- list(
  name = lapply( lapply(sapply(skill_L,sapply,"[","name"),f), unlist ),
  type = lapply( lapply(sapply(skill_L,sapply,"[","type"),f), unlist ),
  aaa  = lapply( lapply(sapply(skill_L,sapply,"[","aaa" ),f), unlist ),
  bbb  = lapply( lapply(sapply(skill_L,sapply,"[","bbb" ),f), unlist )
)
```

.

```
> skill$name
$skills
[1] NA

$skills
    name     name 
"OpenGL"      "C" 

$skills
 <NA>  name  name 
   NA "abc"   "E"
```

.

```
> skill$type
$skills
[1] NA

$skills
  type   <NA> 
"link"     NA 

$skills
  <NA>   type   <NA> 
    NA "Link"     NA
```

.

```
> skill$aaa
$skills
[1] NA

$skills
<NA> <NA> 
  NA   NA 

$skills
  aaa  <NA>   aaa 
  "X"    NA "123"
```

.

```
> skill$bbb
$skills
[1] NA

$skills
<NA> <NA> 
  NA   NA 

$skills
 <NA>   bbb  <NA> 
   NA "xyz"    NA
```

Comment: I have edited my question as I didnt gave enough info. Your solution worked quite nice but the problem is that is also includes other fields, such as skills/type( Haven't included that before in the question). How can I overpass that with your solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lapply` (which is however also a loop), but the code becomes much shorter:

```
sampleData <- list(list(id = "abc",
                        currentCompany = "",
                        skills = list()),
                   list(id = "abc2",
                        currentCompany = "xyz",
                        skills = list(list(name = "OpenGL"),
                                 list(name = "C"))))

lapply(sampleData, function(l) {
   if (length(l$skills) == 0) {
      NA
   } else {
      unlist(l$skills)
   }
})
# [[1]]
# [1] NA

# [[2]]
#     name     name 
# "OpenGL"      "C"
```

**Update**

Quick (and dirty) benchmark results shows that `lapply` is about 50% faster. NB: `createData` can be done smarter too.

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(lps(createData(1e4)), lply(createData(1e4)), unit = "s")
# Unit: seconds
#                     expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq
#   lps(createData(10000)) 1.1829743 1.2541602 1.3069261 1.2873486 1.3478340
#  lply(createData(10000)) 0.5331418 0.5613532 0.6009065 0.5926779 0.6294598
#        max neval cld
#  1.4960136   100   b
#  0.8075482   100  a
```

**Code**

```
createData <- function(length.out) {
   ret <- vector("list", length.out)
   for (i in seq_len(length.out)) {
      skills.n <- sample(0:10, 1)
      skills <- vector("list", skills.n)
      for (j in seq_len(skills.n)) {
         skills[[j]] <- list(name = paste0("skill = ", j, ", id = ", i))
      }
      ret[[i]] <- list(id = paste("id", i),
                       currentCompany = paste("Company", i),
                       skills = skills)
   }
   ret
}

lply <- function(sampleData) {
   lapply(sampleData, function(l) {
      if (length(l$skills) == 0) {
         NA
      } else {
         unlist(l$skills)
      }
   })
}

lps <- function(sampleData) {
   skill <- list()
   for (i in 1:length(sampleData)){
      skill[i][1] <- 'empty'
      for (j in 1:length(sampleData[[i]]$skills)){
         if (length(sampleData[[i]]$skills) == 0){
            skill[[i]][j] <- NA
         }else{
            skill[[i]][j] <- sampleData[[i]]$skills[[j]]$name  
         }
      }
   }
   skill
}
```

Comment: with only one expresion in `{...}` you can omit the braces.

Comment: Sure, but I usually keep them for readability reasons and if I want to add something later I do not have to bother abour braces anymore

Comment: `lapply` is much more than 50% faster than the `for`-loops. Notice that you included `createData(1e+4)` in the benchmark test, which wastes a lot of time.

Comment: Sure, but I was thinking that the offset in timing should be comparable? That is, of course it will slow down `for` but so it will `lapply` and I was thinking that this comes at the same price. Doesn't it?